# Converting Dataset of column to Json format in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

spark version - 2.2
Java 1.8

I have a column in Dataset of string type, But I want to convert it JSON format.

I tried by using **to_json**  method. This is working fine but it's adding extra square brackets in json content due to this front end pages are not loading up.

But I tried in windows(in local), content is coming properly.

Can someone let me know if there is any other way to convert the string or anything missing into JSON method?

```
Input in xml file -

<english_content>
    <aTitle>abc</articleTitle>
    <result_article>abc</search_result_article>
    <content_type_container>
      <web_component>
        <webcomponent_url>text.html</webcomponent_url>
      </web_component>
      <content_type>web_component</content_type>
    </content_type_container>
    <search_result_article_desc>this is test.</search_result_article_desc>
  </english_content>
```

when I use below to_json method directly on input, it is giving me output with Extra Square bracket.

```
 Dataset<Row> ds1 = ds.withColumn("content.serialized",to_json(col("english_content")))
```

the output generated -  Here extra "[" is coming. So it is breaking in front end side.

```
{"Title":"abc","content_type_container":[{"content_type":"web_component","web_component":{"webcomponent_url":"text.html"}}],"result_article":"abc","search_result_article_desc":"this is test."}
```

Expected output - without Square brace.

```
{"Title":"abc","content_type_container":{"content_type":"web_component","web_component":{"webcomponent_url":"text.html"}},"result_article":"abc","search_result_article_desc":"this is test."}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Hi Ramdev, Thanks for getting back to me. Added input and output details. Can you please see into it.

Comment: You should format a bit better your question, it would help... look at struct(), it might help.

Comment: added code i have tried. can u plz see it.Thanks